# Kohnfelder Certificate

Tags: x.509

The Kohnfelder certificate standard is very similar to that of X.509 certificate standard. Comparing the two standards, does one have an advantage edge over the other? or what are the pros and cons of both standards?

Comment: Is Kohnfelder a 'standard' or a concept? I can find no reference to it being implemented on its own but through standards like x.509.

Comment: Kohnfelder wrote a thesis in 1978 from which we have standards like x.509. Your question supposes that his thesis is a standard that can be compared.

Comment: Not that Kohnfelder is a standard on its own but if  a user decides to transmit its already signed certificate to its user community by itself instead of leaving in the CA certificate directory (which is essentially what Kohnfelder's thesis is about) what (if any) are the advantages or disadvantages of that compared to X.509 certificate standard where signed certs are kept in the CA directory for the user community to access. Thanks

Comment: Can you edit your question to include all this background?